# Asp.Net Identity: Edit default layout

Tags: css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I'm trying to create a Dutch application, but I can't seem to figure out where I can remove/edit the default "Manage your account, Change your account settings" text in the account manage view.

I've tried everything I can think of, but not even ctrl+f seems to find a string containing "Manage".

[image: Manage view]

Can anyone point me in the direction of where/how I can edit this English text?

Comment: Try ctrl + shift +F to look in entire solution, not in current document only

Comment: Tried that aswell, didn't show up anything either

Comment: please edit the question and include the view that you are having an issue with

Comment: @DalmTo, that's the problem, I can't figure out which view is causing that, since I never created a view containing 'Manage your account'

Comment: We're having the same problem, the text is certainly not in there when we generate the scaffold code. Where is it coming from? It's things like this that are quickly turning me off asp.net core after 15 years with .net!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using anything newer than ASP.NET Core 2.1 then the Identity source code is provided via a Razor Class library.  If this is the case, I would recommend checking out this [MSDN Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/scaffold-identity?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio).  Based on the documentation you do have the option of bringing the code from the RCL into your project.

> ASP.NET Core 2.1 and later provides ASP.NET Core Identity as a Razor Class Library. Applications that include Identity can apply the scaffolder to selectively add the source code contained in the Identity Razor Class Library (RCL).

Comment: This brings in the scaffold code, but that text is still not in those files either. Maybe something broke with the latest 3.1.2?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem in .NET Core 3.1 Web App. After scaffolding full Identity, manage navbar disappeared. Razor generator didn't create `/Areas/Identity/Pages/_Layout.cshtml`.

The following changes may help:

1. In `/Areas/Identity/Pages/_ViewStart.cshtml` change

   `Layout = "/Pages/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";`

   to

   `Layout = "Account/Manage/_Layout.cshtml"`
2. In `/Areas/Identity/Pages/Account/Manage/_Layout.cshtml` change

   `Layout = "/Areas/Identity/Pages/_Layout.cshtml"`

   to

   `Layout = "/Pages/Shared/_Layout.cshtml"` or your default page layout.

If you can't find these files, you may want to scaffold them.